# ¿Como cambiar el background-color de una etiqueta HTML al utilizar un botón HTML que tiene un enlace?

Tags: html

el motivo de mi consulta es que quiero resaltar el fondo de una etiqueta de texto, ya sea un título, un párrafo, una lista, etc... pero quiero que eso ocurra cuando pulse un botón, dicho botón, funciona como una enlace a esa etiqueta que va a ser resaltada, no tengo conocimientos en JS pero he estado investigando y creo que se puede realizar creando una función en JS y luego añadiendo al botón el evento Onclick, lo he intentado, he buscado información y no me ha funcionado ninguna, gracias.

Comment: Modifica tu pregunta incluyendo esos intentos... así podremos qué note sale y ayudarte en aquello que no sepas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $(".texto1").toggleClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.texto1 {
  background-image: url('../images/imagende_ejemplo1.png');
  /*Si no hay, se pone rojo*/
  background-color: red;
}
.texto1.active {
  background-image: url('../images/imagende_ejemplo2.png');
  /*Si no hay, se pone verde*/
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center><h4>Cambiar fondo de letras al tocar un boton</h4></center>
<button>Cambiar fondo</button>
<div class="texto1"> !Hola! </div>
```

¿Eso es lo que buscabas no? Deberias ser mas explicito con lo que buscas.